# How to download CardConnect library by using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to use https://github.com/Dewbud/CardConnect this library in my project but don't know how to download by using composer, library developer does not mention in the documentation.

Comment: please add "CardConnect" and "Composer" to the question's tags.
please tell us why you want to do it this way.

Comment: What have yout ried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are listed at [Packgist](https://packagist.org/packages/dewbud/cardconnect) which means you can either add it to your project from the command line using the following command:

```
composer require dewbud/cardconnect
```

Or by adding the following to your `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    "dewbud/cardconnect" : "2.*"
}
```

Comment: Do not recommend using `*` in version constraints. That's pretty bad and risky. Proper approach is documented here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md